# Check Site URL which fills data in Report Suite in SiteCatalyst (Omniture)

Tags: adobe-analytics

This question may seems odd but we have a slight mixup within our Report Suites on Omniture (SiteCatalyst). Multiple Report Suites are generating analytics and it's hard for us to find which site URL is constituting the results.

Hence my question is, is there any way we can find which Site is filling data within a certain Report Suite.

Through this following JS, I am able to find which "report suite" is being used by a certain site though:-

```
javascript:void(window.open("","dp_debugger","width=600,height=600,location=0,menubar=0,status=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1").document.write("<script language=\"JavaScript\" id=dbg src=\"https://www.adobetag.com/d1/digitalpulsedebugger/live/DPD.js\"></"+"script>"));
```

But I am hoping to find the other way around that where Report Suite gets its data from within the SiteCatalyst admin.

Any assistance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Analytics (formerly SiteCatalyst) does not have anything native or built in to globally look at all data coming to see which page/site is sending data to which report suite. However, you *can* contact Adobe ClientCare and request raw hit logs for a date range, and you can parse those logs yourself, if you really want.

Alternatively, if you have Data Warehouse access, you can export urls and domains from there for a given date range. You can only select one report suite at a time but that's also better than nothing, if you really need the historical data now.

Another alternative is if your sites are NOT currently setting `s.pageName`, then you may be in some measure of luck for your historical data.  The pages report is popped from `s.pageName` value. If you do not set that variable, it will default to the URL of the web page that made the request. So, at a minimum you will be able to see your URLs in that report right now, so that should help you out. And if you define "site" as equivalent of "domain" (`location.hostname`) you can also setup a classification level for pages for domain and then use the Classification Rule Builder and a regular expression to pop the classification with the domain, which will give you some aggregated numbers.

**Some suggestions moving forward...**

I good strategy moving forward is to have all of your sites report to a global report suite. Then, you can have each site *also* send data to a site level report suite (warning: make sure you have enough server calls in your contract to cover this, since AA does not have unlimited server calls). Alternatively, you can stick with one global report suite and setup segments for each site. Another alternative is to create a rollup report suite to have all data from your other report suites to also go to. Rollup report suites do not have as many features as standard report suites, but for basic things such as pages, page views, it works.

The overall point though is that one way or the other, you should have all of your data go into one report suite as the first step.

Then, you should also assign a few custom variables to be output on the pages of all your sites. These are the 4 main things I always try to include in an implementation to make it easier to find out which sites/pages are reporting to what.

- A custom variable to identify the site. Some people use `s.server` for this. However, you may also want to pop a `prop` or `eVar` with the value as well, depending on how you'd like to be able to break data down. The big question here is: How do you define "site" ? I have seen it defined many different ways.
- If you do NOT define "site" as domain (e.g. `location.hostname`) then I suggest you pop a `prop` and `eVar` with the domain, because AA does not have a native report for this. But if you do, then you can skip this, since it's same thing as point #1
- A custom `prop` and `eVar` with the report suites(s).  Unless you have a super old version of legacy code, just set it with `s.sa()`. This will ensure you get the final report suite(s), in case you happen to use a version that uses Dynamic Account variables (e.g. `s.dynamicAccountList`).
- If you set `s.pageName` with a custom value, then I suggest you pop a `prop` and `eVar` with the URL. *Tip:* to save on request url length to AA, you can use dynamic variable syntax to copy the `g` parameter already in a given AA request. For example (assuming you don't have code that changes the dynamic variable prefix): `s.prop1='D=g';` Or, you can pop this with a processing rule if you have the access.

Answer (score 0):

you can normally find this sort of information in the Site Content-> Servers report. There will be information in there the indicates what sites are sending in the hits. Your milage may vary based on the actual tagging implementation, it is not common for anyone to explicitly set the server, so the implicit value is the domain the hit is coming in from.

Thanks C.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I may be blind, but I do not see this reflected in the online documentation?

Comment: I do not believe the default behavior is documented. Do check it out though and let me know if your experience differs. I believe there are a set of default rules that kick in when certain values are not set. For example if someone forgets to set the page name variable, then the page url is used for page name as a fall back. I think we are seeing this here.

Comment: Also this is a good way to see if some random site is sending hits into your report suites, the results are sometimes surprising.

Comment: Yeah but the docs do show the [`pageName` defaults to URL](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/pageName.html) even though core code doesn't explicitly set it (you won't see it in request URL if you don't set it). But if you look at [`server`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/server.html) it shows empty string as default.  But it could totally be mis-documentation..

Comment: Truth be told, I've never actually tried NOT setting it to see what happens, but I'll give it a go and find out! You are right; if it DOES do this by default then that could be useful for him (assuming he's not setting it, of course)

Comment: Okay Chris, so I actually did find one a clients that does not set `s.server` and I also did my own test on my own account and I can confirm that `s.server` does NOT default to popping domain in the reports.  The server report shows no data.